# How to delete everything inside a parenthesis without deleting the parenthesis in Vim?

Tags: vim

Let say I have a block of code like this:

```js
await store.dispatch(getLicensesThunk('content', submission))
```

And I want to delete everything inside the `getLicensesThunk` **excluding the parenthesis**, what command should I use?

```js
await store.dispatch(getLicensesThunk())
```

I currently use `d%` for this, but it will delete the parenthesis as well, which is not something I want.

```js
await store.dispatch(getLicensesThunk)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`d%` can't do what you want because it is "inclusive", which means that it includes the characters at the beginning and end of the motion and therefore that it will swallow your parentheses.

Vim has a special kind of motion that can be used after an operator called "text objects". They are described under `:help text-object`, which is one of the most mind-blowing sections of the built-in documentation.

The one you are looking for is `:help i(` for "inner parentheses":

```
di(
```

Comment: Also, it may be more comfortable to type `b` instead of `(` or `)`.

Comment: @dedObed indeed I always use `ibabiBaB` instead of `i(a(i{a{` for that reason and I even have made my own `irar` for `[]`. But I figured that a) this wasn't super relevant and b) the information can be found in the relevant help section anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use `di(` to delete everything inside parentheses. This also works for double quotes (`di"`) and a few more paired characters.

The cursor can be anywhere between the parentheses.